# How to list only the runtimeClasspath resolved dependencies in Gradle during a build?

Tags: java, gradle

I am trying to create a task in my build that will list all the runtimeClasspath dependencies before it builds the project. So basically, it should be the equivalent of the following command but for all the subprojects:

```
gradle dependencies --configuration runtimeClasspath
```

So far I have managed to come up with a task that lists all the dependencies:

```
subprojects {
   task listDependencies(type: DependencyReportTask) {}

   complileJava.dependsOn listDependencies
}
```

It works great in the sense that it lists all the dependencies of all the subprojects, but as mentioned above, it also lists a lot of stuff I don't need to see.

How do I limit the output of the above task to just runtimeClasspath?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are defining a task of type `DependencyReportTask`, you can configure its configuration property, which will be the equivalent of the `--configuration` flag on the CLI.

So something like:

```
subprojects {
    def listDeps = tasks.register("listDependencies", DependencyReportTask) {
        setConfiguration("runtimeClasspath")
    }

    tasks.withType(JavaCompile).configureEach {
        dependsOn(listDeps)
    }
}
```

Note however that printing the `runtimeClasspath` before executing `compileJava` is a bit weird. The classpath used by the compile task will be `compileClasspath`.

**Edited to use lazy task API as there is otherwise an ordering problem with plugin application**

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. I get:
`> Configuration with name 'compileClasspath' not found.`

Comment: Edited my answer to use lazy task API so that there is no ordering problem between applying the java plugin and configuring this task

Comment: Just tried - it did not change the result - still erroring...

Comment: Please update the question with a more complete example then. Maybe you have some subprojects that do not apply any java plugin.

Comment: They all have `plugins {
    id 'java'
}` - is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. I fixed my example, I was mixing lazy and eager task configuration, which was breaking in some case. Should be good now.

Comment: This works! How you came up with this is beyond me... Thanks for your help!

Comment: Definitely something that needs to be done in the documentation around evaluation ordering and how the lazy approach helps.

Comment: Would you be able to provide a Kotlin version of this code?

Answer (score 2):

A Kotlin version of the above accepted answer:

```
val listDeps = tasks.register<DependencyReportTask>("listDependencies") {
    setConfiguration("compileClasspath")
}

tasks.withType<JavaCompile> {
    dependsOn(listDeps)
}
```